# log files -- rsync -- loadbalancer

Tags: load-balancing

My server setup is this

server1,server2,server3

server2 and server3 are synced to server1 using Rsync

all are load balanced.....

the problem I have here is that my applications log files are being overwritten.....
Can you guys suggest any solution

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you're using the "--delete" arugment on rsync, eh? If it's not too obivous, you could store the logs somewhere outside of the directory structure that's being rsync'd. If you don't have control over the log file storage location, you could always use the "--exclude" argument on rsync.